# Wine and ip camera tool

Tags: ip, camera

I installed an IP camera tool using wine in ubuntu 14.04 LTS, in order to configure IP cameras. The IP camera tool's icon is on my desktop, but when I double click on it, the application does not open. What could it be wrong?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. please let us know more about your program name and version, your installation procedure, In your case you did not say anything about your problem

Answer (score 0):

this may be related to having to run the application in legacy mode.
However, I don't think you need this software in the first place. check the manual, the ipcamera may have a web interface. use a browser to go to that address. and do the setup there. which ipcamera brand/model are you trying to configure?